# Rails Routes: Nested Scopes/Namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, namespaces, scope

Right now I have an admin.domain.com subdomain for which there is a module scope:

```
  constraints(AdminDomain) do
    scope :module => "admin" do
      resources :visitors
    end
  end
```

This makes all requests on the admin subdomain hit controllers in app/controllers/admin/.

What I'd like to do now is something like:

```
  constraints(AdminDomain) do
    scope :module => "admin" do
      resources :visitors
      scope "history", :as => "history" do
        resources :visitors
      end
    end
  end
```

Where the end goal is to make admin.domain.com/history/visitors hit controller: app/controllers/admin/history/visitors_controller.rb.

This path however still looks for app/controllers/admin/visitors_controller.rb.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`namespace` is what I was looking for:

```
  constraints(AdminDomain) do
    scope :module => "admin" do
      resources :visitors
      namespace :history do
        resources :visitors
      end
    end
  end
```

And I had to define `Admin::History::VisitorsController` in `app/controllers/admin/history/visitors_controller.rb`

Answer (score 0):

easy way to define specific controller is just like:

```
:controller => admin/history/visitors
```